# Java multiple class inheritance across multiple files

Tags: java, inheritance

I am trying to inherit classes from different files.

1. When I just call a class that's in different file, it works.
2. When I call a class that's in and different file, that inherits from a class in a third file, I get an error like `error: cannot find symbol`

```
//ClassA.java

public class ClassA{
    public void setPossibleJumpRight() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

```
//Main.java

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
    }
}
```

The above works for me

```
//ClassA.java

public class ClassA{
    public void DoSomething() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

```
//ClassB.java

public class ClassB extends ClassA{
    public void DoSomethingElse() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

```
//Main.java

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassB classVar = new ClassB();
    }
}
```

The above does not work for me. I get an error like `error: cannot find symbol` when trying to reference an instance variable of the class I'm trying to inherit from.

I've checked out some other SO answers so no avail.

1. [How can I separate classes into different files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40210439/how-can-i-separate-classes-into-different-files)
2. [How do i use a class from a different file in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746502/how-do-i-use-a-class-from-a-different-file-in-java)

How can I inherit across multiple files like this?

Comment: What do you mean by _does not work for me_. What error are you getting ?

Comment: Can you verify that you're actually using `static` and not "staic"?  Otherwise this should be closed as a typo.  And get a compiler / IDE that gives better error messages, this should be obvious.

Comment: Yes, I am using static and not staic.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not correct. First, you can't name a variable `var` (that's a reserved word). Second you can't invoke a constructor without parenthesis.

```
ClassB var = new ClassB;
```

should be

```
ClassB v = new ClassB();
```

You can't rename `main` to `Main` (like `public staic void Main(String[] args) {`). The class has a capital letter. The method name **must** be lowercase `main`. And

```
ClassA var = new Class A
```

needs to be like

```
ClassA a = new ClassA();
```

Your edits are introducing ever more typos. This

```
public class Main{
    public staic void main(String[] args) {
        ClassA var = new Class A
    }
}
```

would need to be like

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassA v = new ClassA();
    }
}
```

Comment: `var` is not a reserved word in Java.

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassB classVar = new ClassB();
    }
}
```

static in place of staic